# Separating database config from connection

Tags: php, mysql, database, pdo

I'm trying to make a connection to the database while having the database config information saperated from the connection.

This is the code I wrote

db config information:

```
$config = array(
"database" => array(
   "host" => "host",
   "username" => "username",
   "password" => "password",
   "name" => "name",
)
);

define("databse_config", $config["database"]);
```

***$config*** normaly also contains other information not relevant to the question ,that is why I have defined "database_config".

database connection:

```
require_once "config.php";
define("DB_HOST", databse_config['host']);
define("DB_USERNAME", databse_config['username']);
define("DB_PASSWORD", databse_config['password']);
define("DB_NAME", databse_config['name']);

function connect()
{
    $dbhost = DB_HOST;
    $dbuser = DB_USERNAME;
    $dbpass = DB_PASSWORD;
    $dbname = DB_NAME;

    try {
        $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname", $dbuser, $dbpass);
        $conn->exec("set names utf8");
        $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        return $conn;
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }
}

connect();
```

The problem I keep running in to is that wile trying to execute the function the page keeps loading and eventualy outputs the following error:

> Connection failed: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection timed out

I'm fairly new to PDO so I also tried the same while using mysqli, which gave the same result.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I have a feeling that you've gone with your separation a bit too far. isn't **two** blocks of constants definition and **three** blocks of variable definitions a bit too much for the task? Can't you just use databse_config inside connect()?

Comment: Hi, I have already tried doing that. I have also tried running the code without it being a function and it still wont work.

Comment: Exactly. So your question is not how to separate but how to fix the error?

Comment: yes exactly. I should have been more specific with the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Connection failed: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection timed out

This means php tried to establish a TCP/IP connection to  your database server AND FAILED. You provided a `DB_HOST` hostname that's unreachable by network from the location of your php program.

The hostname value could be missing, or it could be wrong.  If you provided it by name (`mysql-server.example.com`), this error message tells you the DNS name lookup succeeded.

So your php sends out a request to  the server for a TCP/IP connection. That request never gets a response.  That means there's a firewall somewhere blocking the connection, or that there's no network route from your php program to the network.

This all means the `$dbhost` value is wrong in your `new PDO()` operation.

Your code could be simplified a lot like this with no loss of modularity. [`sprintf()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) helps. Simpler is better for troubleshooting.

```
require_once "config.php";
function connect()
{
    try {
        $connectionString = sprintf ("mysql:host=%s;dbname=%s", 
                                      database_config['host'],
                                      database_config['name']);
        $conn = new PDO($connectionString, 
                        database_config['username'],
                        database_config['password']);
        $conn->exec("set names utf8");
        $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        return $conn;
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }
}    
connect();
```

And you can `echo $connectionString;` to see what's in it, and make sure it isn't something bizarre.

Comment: Hi,

Thanks for your reaction. All the details I have given to the connection should be good. I have made a connection to the database before but then I did not separate the database config. The only difference now is that all de details are being provided in array form and from a config file.

Comment: Right. Still, I suggest you troubleshoot backward from your failure point. My point is that your clue is a bad server hostname.

Comment: I'm sorry, you were totaly right. I backtracked what I had changed since it worked, and found out that somewhere along the lines I change the hostname. Thank you very much!!